# How to best setup a click event when I have 3 different functions as possibilities

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I will use in my application, and the actual onClick event can have 3 possibilites:

```
1. function#1
2. function#2
3. no click event
```

So based on a condition, how can I wireup the correct event on the component?

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
  _handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked user component');
  }

  render() {
    return(
         <div className="user-component" onClick={::this._handleClick}> ... </div>
    );
  }
```

}

Would I just use a switch statement?

Or create a function that would then optionally fire one of the 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the handle function for your click event to be a routing function. determine what it needs to do from some context and then do that thing

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
  possibility1() {
    console.log('possibility one called')
  }
  possibility2() {
    console.log('possibility two called')
  }
  _handleClick() {
    if (!this.props.someImportantThing) {
      console.log('possibility three, no event called')
      return
    }
    if (this.props.someOtherThing) {
      this.possibility1()
    } else {
      this.possibility2()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
         <div className="user-component" onClick={::this._handleClick}> ... </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

## Edit

if this component is only firing one of those functions, but it needs to be able to fire of a conditional function you can use it like a prop.

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
  _handleClick(e) {
    this.props.handleClick && this.props.handleClick(e)
  }
  render() {
    return(
         <div className="user-component" onClick={::this._handleClick}> ... </div>
    );
  }
}
```

then you would use it like this

```
<UserComponent handleClick={possibility1} /> // I run possibility1 function only
<UserComponent handleClick={possibility2} /> // I run possibility2 function only
<UserComponent /> // I dont run any handler function at all
```

Comment: or is it better to pass in the state whenever I use the component, i feel the component shouldn't have this much logic in the onClick.  Well kind of going back and forth on it hehe.

Comment: Wait are you saying this component will only use one possibility? meaning one instance of it only uses possibility 1 and one instance only uses possibility 2... etc

Answer (score 0):

Inside of _handleClick id fire the correct function based on the event. This would be does fairly easily if the event is passed as a prop or is held in some app wide state like redux.